# Going through a label loop

Tags: loops, label, output, goto, basic

I am having trouble going through a loop that I created through a label. The loop is supposed to go through 100 times and print out the according messages if it is divisible by 3, by 5, or if its divisible by 3 and 5. I am new to basic and am using the bridge water interpreter to compile the program. Here is the source code. The program runs until the "second part" print message and then no output. I have tried to rewrite the loop but I still cant get it to work. We are supposed to use only if-then and goto functions

```
print "Enter product cost."
input productCost
print "Enter in amount paid."
input amountPaid
if amountPaid < productCost then
   print "Insufficient amount paid. Program exiting."
stop
end if
if amountPaid >= productCost then
   change = amountPaid - productCost
   dollars = int(change / 1)
   quarters = int(change / .25)
   dimes = int(change /  .10)
   nickles = int(change / .05)
   pennies = int(change / .01)

   print "Change in dollars: ";  dollars
   print "Change in quarters: "; quarters
   print "Change in dimes: "; dimes
   print "Change in nickles: "; nickles
   print "Change in pennies: "; pennies
end if
print "Entering second part of the program."
totalIterations = 1
secondPart:
if totalIterations < 100 then  
   if totalIterations / 3 = 0 And totalIterations / 5 = 0 then
      print "The number: " + totalIterations + " is FizzBuzz"
      totalIterations = totalIterations + 1
   end if
   if totalIterations / 3 = 0 And totalIterations / 5 > 0 then
      print "The number: " + totalIterations + " is Fizz"
      totalIterations = totalIterations + 1
   end if
   if totalIterations / 3 > 0 And totalIterations / 5 = 0 then
      print "The number: " + totalIterations + " is Buzz"
      totalIterations = totalIterations + 1
   end if
end if
goto secondPart
```

Answer (score 0):

You only increment `totalIterations` inside the inner `if`s - which are never entered. You should move it to the "main" `if`, so that you continue incrementing it even if it isn't divisible by 3 or 5:

```
totalIterations = 1
secondPart:
if totalIterations < 100 then  
   if totalIterations / 3 = 0 And totalIterations / 5 = 0 then
      print "The number: " + totalIterations + " is FizzBuzz"
   end if
   if totalIterations / 3 = 0 And totalIterations / 5 > 0 then
      print "The number: " + totalIterations + " is Fizz"
   end if
   if totalIterations / 3 > 0 And totalIterations / 5 = 0 then
      print "The number: " + totalIterations + " is Buzz"
   end if
   totalIterations = totalIterations + 1
end if
goto secondPart
```

Comment: I tried doing that originally, but I get the same issue. When I compile and run the mammogram this is the output in my terminal window.Enter product cost.
? 500
Enter in amount paid.
? 600
Change in dollars:  100
Change in quarters:  400
Change in dimes:  1000
Change in nickles:  2000
Change in pennies:  10000
Entering second part of the program. Never executes the code that is in the label

Comment: I think you made a couple of boobs in the above comment!

Comment: "When I compile and run the ..." - it looks like you didn't keep abreast of your auto-correct.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> totalIterations = 1
> secondPart:
> if totalIterations < 100 then  
>   ...
> end if
> goto secondPart
> ```

No matter what you write on the ... , this is an infinite loop. Since you state that "We are supposed to use only `if-then` and `goto` functions", solve the looping issue by writing:

```
totalIterations = 1
secondPart:
...
if totalIterations < 100 then goto secondPart
```

But wait, with these numbers the loop will only run **99** times! Moreover you only increment the *totalIterations* variable within the test cases, which means that if none is true the variable won't advance at all. Solving both issues leads to:

```
totalIterations = 0
secondPart:
totalIterations = totalIterations + 1
...
if totalIterations < 100 then goto secondPart
```

---

> ```
> if totalIterations / 3 = 0 And totalIterations / 5 = 0 then
> if totalIterations / 3 = 0 And totalIterations / 5 > 0 then
> if totalIterations / 3 > 0 And totalIterations / 5 = 0 then
> ```

**None of the above test divisibility**.

In the absence of any type suffix, BASIC will have treated your *totalIterations* variable as a floating point value on which you then perform a regular division operation, producing a fractional part that will render all of these `and`'s FALSE. That would have been a second reason that your program got stuck in an infinite loop.

The solution is in the BASIC `mod` operator which returns the remainder from the equivalent division. I can't possibly know what BASIC variant you're using but many of them will allow a suffix of **%** to define a variable an integer. This is what you need:

```
if (totalIterations% mod 15) = 0 then
  print "The number: ";totalIterations%;" is FizzBuzz"
end if
if (totalIterations% mod 3) = 0 then
  print "The number: ";totalIterations%;" is Fizz"
end if
if (totalIterations% mod 5) = 0 then
  print "The number: ";totalIterations%;" is Buzz"
end if
```